# Schmidt decomposition of bipartite states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra

When performing the Schmidt decomposition of a bipartite state $\left|\psi\right>_{AB}=\sum_{ij}c_{ij}\left|v_i\right>_{A}\left|w_j\right>_{B}$ is computing the eigenvectors of the reduced density matrices $\rho_{A}=CC^{\dagger}$ and $\rho_{B}=C^{\dagger}C$ to the eigenvalues $\sigma(CC^{\dagger})=\sigma(C^{\dagger}C)=\{\lambda_{i}\}_{i}$ (singular values of $C$), denoted by $\{\left|a_i\right>_{A}\}$, $\{\left|b_i\right>_{B}\}$, in order to decompose the state like $\left|\psi\right>_{AB}=\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}\left|a_i\right>_{A}\left|b_i\right>_{B}$ a general procedure which always works? Do I have to try in a different manner when having multiple singular values? The state I'm tryng to decompose is 
$\left|\psi\right>_{AB}=\frac{1}{2}(\left|00\right>+\left|01\right>+\left|10\right>-\left|11\right>)$, for which this method doesn't seem to work.

$\left|\psi\right>_{AB}=\frac{1}{2}(\left|00\right>+\left|01\right>+\left|10\right>-\left|11\right>)$ leads to the coefficients matrix

$
   C=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
   \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$,

which in turn results in the reduced density matrices

$
   \rho_{A}=CC^{\dagger}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
   0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \end{array} } \right]=C^{\dagger}C=\rho_{B}
$.

Thus, the reduced density matrices share the eigenvectors $\left|0\right>$ and $\left|1\right>$ for the repetead eigenvalue $\frac{1}{2}$. I thought then the bipartite state could have been decomposed like $\left|\psi\right>_{AB}=\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}\left|a_i\right>_{A}\left|b_i\right>_{B}$, using the singular values and the eigenvectors of $\rho_{A}$ and $\rho_{B}$. However, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|0\right>\otimes\left|0\right>+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|1\right>\otimes\left|1\right>$ does not yield the state I wanted to decompose.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does it not work? You have to add details, your question is unclear as it is now.

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do. To find the Schmidt decomposition you need only find the SVD of $C$ (which in this case is also symmetric, making the task easier). You cannot reconstruct the state from the reduced density matrices, like you seem to be trying to do